# CakePHP - Behaviours/Behaviors - Advice on creating custom behaviour

Tags: cakephp, model, bdd, behavior

I read up on behaviours and thought it might suit my simple requirements but i don't know how to get started in terms of creating a custom behaviour.

Scenario: 
I have a *master* table called **Companies**. This table has a "hasMany" relationship to *detail tables* **BusinessDescriptions** and **Addresses**. Of course, these detail tables are linked to the Companies table by a **foreign key**.

Despite the "hasMany" relationship, **only one record in these detail tables can be valid on any particular day.** Hence in the *detail tables* for BusinessDescriptions and Addresses, I have fields "**Startdate**" and "**Enddate**" which tell you what time period the records are valid for.

Example use: Company X will have a new address from 01.01.2015. Hence when inserting the new address, its old address record which is valid from Startdate 01.01.2014 to Enddate 31.12.9999, needs to have its Enddate changed to 31.12.2014, to make way for the new record that starts from 01.01.2015.

All this "auto-delimitation/adjustment" of start/end dates of existing records, I wish to put into a behaviour, however tutorials on getting a custom behavior up and running are hard to find.

Can anyone point out to me how to start, or maybe show me skeletal structure of creating a behaviour for this?

Comment: I expect most of the logic to detect overlaps comparing the new record to existing records to be done in the model behaviour code, while the controller may make calls to the model/behavior functions as necessary, passing relevant information. But yes i dont really know how to get started

Comment: You learn a lot from looking at existing (plugin) behaviors, from simple ones to more [complicated ones](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Model/Behavior/RevisionBehavior.php). That should get you started on how to write things in your behavior then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for a Behavior on this one.  Behaviors are for when you need to utilize logic across multiple Models - in this case, it seems you only need it on one model.

You might just use the `beforeFind()` callback in your `Company` model.  It in, you can append the conditions for the date(s) you want to restrict by.

If you really want to make a behavior, you could put that `beforeFind()` into one, and utilize it any time you want said model to restrict based on the current date...etc.

On a side note, why not just retrieve the most recent address for that company? Order by the date DESC, and limit 1 ?